# KIA Sedona 2003 Diesel Intercooler Turbo Low Fuel Mileage

Tags: diesel, fuel-consumption, kia, sedona

I have a 2003 a Kia Sedona turbo diesel 2.9L, with intercooler.

I am getting 5 km per liter of diesel consumed. I also have to do oil change and ATF replacement. I got the car 3 weeks ago.

What are the possible remedies to improve fuel consumption? Other Sedona owners are getting 8 to 10 km/L on city and 12km/L on highway?

Will oil and ATF change improve mileage? Old oil is likely black and old ATF is smelly and like diesel?

How about fuel filter, injector cleaner, and whatever may be suggested?

Comment: How is your exhaust pipe? Is it black and sooty? Can you smell fuel? Is there any color to the exhaust smoke?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd check is to see if there are any leaks in the intake tract. Make sure all of your cold pipes (pressure side between turbo and intake manifold, going through the intercooler) are in place and not leaking, especially at the joints.

The turbo may be at fault as well. If it has failed, this could be causing a loss of power and excess use of fuel. If you have a boost gauge, you can see that a lack of boost is being built under engine stress. You might also hear what would be considered "more than normal" (or none at all) turbo whine.

If your injectors are dumping too much fuel (stuck open or not closing all the way), you'll obviously be getting poor fuel economy.

Change the oil and ATF, but neither of these should have any real impact as you are suggesting, though bad oil or lack of oil can cause premature turbo bearing failure.

While not any news to you, I'd suspect you should be getting somewhere around 40-42 miles per gallon, where right now it appears you are getting around 11-12 MPG. That is SUCKY!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but here's what I found recently on my 2.9 CRDi.

I had an instant, massive increase in fuel consumption, lots of black smoke in 1st and 2nd even under light acceleration. Air filter was clean, and there were no air leaks. Turns out the MAF sensor was bad, telling the ECU there was lots of air entering the engine, causing it to add far too much fuel. Disconnected the sensor and the smoke stopped, while fuel economy is *way* better than before the MAF went bad. The downside - not much power. But it's great for long distance driving in flat areas.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Do you know for sure if it's safe to run without the MAF plugged in? I think I'd recommend getting a new, working MAF with all that money saved from not-wasted gas.